# Unexpected conversion of inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to make a kind of "collection". This class needs to accept all classes that inherits from a base class.

For example:

Imagine that we have a base class called "A", and we have a lot of other classes that inherits from this class "A". So we have, class "B" that inherits from "A", class "C" that inherits from "A", and so on, and we have a class called "collection" that also inherits from "A". The class "collection" has a "std::map" where keep all classes saved using the "add" method and can be retrieved using "get".

What is happening is that it works somehow, but the application converts to the "base class" instead of return the class that is passed.

Let's go to the code (see the comments on the code to understand the output):

This is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void saySomething()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from A object" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void saySomething()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from B object" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C : public A
{
    void saySomething()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from C object" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Collection : public A
{
public:
    void add(const std::string & key, A * value)
    {
        storage[key] = value;
    }
    A * get(const std::string & key)
    {
        return storage[key];
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, A *> storage;
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{

    B * b = new B;
    C * c = new C;
    Collection * col = new Collection;
    Collection * col2 = new Collection;
    col->add("b", b); // works, because "b" inherits from "A" class.
    col->add("c", c); // works, because "c" inherits from "A" class.
    col->add("col2", col2); // watch this part...
    col->get("b")->saySomething(); // works - Output: Hello from B object
    col->get("c")->saySomething(); // works - Output: Hello from C object
    return 0;

}
```

It works, but when I try to retrieve the "col2" and use his methods...

```
col->get("col2")->add("b", b);
// output: error: 'class A' has no member named 'add'
```

If I'm not wrong, it needed to works, because the "get" method returns the object, so I have the methods of the "col2" object right? If you answer yes, we have the same thought, and I have no idea what is happening. On the "b" and "c" object it returns the object and I have the "saySomething" methods, but when i try to retrieve the "col2", it has the object as an "A" object, so the error:

> 'class A' has no member named 'add'

And it get worse if I do this:

```
col->get("col2")->saySomething(); // output: Hello from A object
```

The idea is that, a collection that accepts only classes that inherits from a base class and also accepts others collections that inherits from the same base class, like recursively.

Comment: And you are surprised? Your `get` call returns an `A*`, and does `A*` have an `add()` method? Additionally, your `Collection` class *inherits* from `A`, but does *not override* the method `saySomething()`, so why are you surprised by the output?

Comment: Do not use public inheritance, unless the inherited class "is a" of the parent. `Collection` is not a `A`, therefore it is poor design to publicly inherit it from `A`.

Comment: You need to cast to `Collection` if you want to access methods that are not part of `A`s interface.

Comment: @Nim - What you said doesn't make sense, because I know that A doesn't implement the method "get" but what matters is that the "collection" that inherits from A has that method.

Comment: @tillaert - Can you explain more this to me, please?

Comment: @Hulk - Examples? Please. I know that you are trying to help, but avoid generic answers. - cast you mean "dynamic_cast" or "static_cast" or what? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but your `get()` call is returning something that *looks* like `A`, and where ever you use it, you can *only use it* as if it *were* an `A`. If at the place where you call `get()` you need to access something that looks like `Collection`, then you need to *cast* the returned pointer and check that it is indeed a `Collection`, for this you must use `dynamic_cast<>`.

Comment: @Nim - This is what I'm saying, in logical it needed to work, because we know that classes, templates, abstract classes and so on are "types", so what I'm doing is also known as "type hinting", and it works, the method accepts classes that inherits from A, but it converts and instead of return the class that was accepted, returns A. Strange huh? - What you think about people saying that dynamic_cast is dangerous, and if it was your problem, how would you do or fix this.

Comment: @Nim - Pay attention in what I said on the end of the question: "The idea is that, a collection that accepts only classes that inherits from a base class and also accepts others collections that inherits from the same base class, like recursively." - Thank you Nim.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, I'm just trying to explain to you why it's not working as you expect. The object you put into the `Collection` may be another `Collection`, but when you use `get()`, you get back a pointer to an object that *looks* like `A` (i.e. has `A`'s interface), if you want it to be treated as a `Collection`, you have to cast it. I'm pragmatic, if this is what's needed do it, but it's really down to you as it's your problem to solve...

Comment: I understood what you said.I want the best solution, you know, but if I don't find, I will chose the one that works well, because I really can't see other ways to do this.
What's funny is that this works in other languages without problems, but this isn't the case here. Thank you @Nim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has static typing, so when you have an object of type `A` - and this is what your `get` method returns - only methods declared in `A` can be used. To call `add` on the result of `get` you either need to cast with `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`, or rethink your class hierarchy altogether. Why `Collection` needs to inherit from `A`? (And to answer your last question, since it inherits, if you call `saySomething` it will call the method declared in `A` because `Collection` does not provide its own override).

Comment: "The idea is that, a collection that accepts only classes that inherits from a base class and also accepts others collections that inherits from the same base class, like recursively." - This is why the Collection inherits from A as well. - Do you have an example about how I can implement those "static_cast" or "dynamic_Cast" on that situation? - I will see more about this, thank you.

Comment: I see the following options for you: 1. casts, e.g. dynamic_cast<Collection*>(col->get("col2"))->add("b", b); (you should test if the cast returned not-null) 2. adding the collection methods to the base class 3. use Visitor design pattern. I think that 1 is the worst - casts are dangerous complication and most often the signal that the design is wrong. You could consider add collection methods to `A` and throw exception in the `A` implementation, while override in `Collection` does what is supposed to do.

Comment: I liked your answer. I saw some posts on internet that says the same about casts, that it's dangerous and so on.
About add the Collection methods on A I tried and I got errors.

Comment: I think you have added only declaration without the function body in braces.

Comment: I did what you said, first I made only the declaration without body in order to see what happen, because the Collection has the method, so probably it will override, but didn't worked, so I declared with body in braces, and it worked. But that I think is: It's strange. I'm saying that class "A" is "everything", imagine if I have more classes, I need to declare all classes on the A? I want class "A" s a type, and that is it. There's a way to i do it without need to declare ALL methods on class A? Thank you.

Comment: The way you seek is Visitor pattern, but it also introduces complication. You will need to decide if it's worth it.

Comment: I will see if it fits to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: - I was searching and I found a guy saying something about "dangling pointers" and "wild pointers" is this what is happening with me? Instead of "get" method return the real pointer, it's returning a "dangling pointer"?

Comment: I found a problem that is more or less like mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773359/right-design-pattern-to-deal-with-polymorphic-collections-of-objects
They have the same thought about "dynamic_cast". Why you think that it's not good to implement? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because adding just two new methods to `A` does not complicate things much, and then the solution is cleaner.