# Toy Compiler Symbol Table

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I'm creating a compiler (for the Cool language) as a personal project and I'm having trouble designing a symbol table. For context, I'm using a hierarchy of classes as my AST. Here's a small snippet of the AST:

```
class NodeAST {
public:
  virtual void accept(Visitor&) = 0;  
};

class ProgramAST : public NodeAST {
private:
  const std::vector<ClassPtr> vClasses;

public:
  ProgramAST(std::vector<ClassPtr> vClasses);

  auto class_cbegin() const { 
    return std::cbegin(vClasses); 
  }
  auto class_cend() const { 
    return std::cend(vClasses); 
  }

  virtual void accept(Visitor& v) override;
};

class ClassAST : public NodeAST {
private:
  const std::string name;
  const std::vector<FeaturePtr> vFeatures; 

public:
  ClassAST(std::string name, std::vector<FeaturePtr> vFeatures);

  auto getName() const { 
    return name; 
  }

  auto feature_cbegin() const { 
    return std::cbegin(vFeatures);
  }
  auto feature_cend() const { 
    return std::cend(vFeatures); 
  }

  virtual void accept(Visitor& v) override;
};
```

Currently, at the core of my symbol table is a map defined as follows:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, NodeAST*> table
```

It maps the name of a declaration to its corresponding node in the AST. That way, for example, I can fill in the types for the loose identifers using the type that I have set in the AST node.

The problem, however, is that when I query the symbol table for a node, I get back a `NodeAST*`. Thus, I have to downcast it to `ClassAST*`, `MethodAST*` or `VarDecAST*` etc. to actually use it.

How do I design my symbol table in a way that avoids the need for downcasting?

Comment: I wouldn't say that downcasting is a necessarily a big problem here. You may know the target type from context. Sure, the downcast could still fail because the Cool source code contains an error, but in that case your `dynamic_cast` fails and you output that as a direct error e.g. `Expected a class, but "Foo" names a function`.

Comment: Maybe: Get rid of the base `NodeAst`and make all `accept` functions a non virtual template. Than, you might have visitors operating differently on each collection type.

Comment: @DieterLücking: There usually is little need to remove a base class; you can still instantiate templates on classes that happen to be related by inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the programming language you are implementing, but I don't think it is really likely that you can avoid dynamic casts completely. For example in `f(1)`, `f` could either be a function or an variable if your language has lambdas. You need to find that out, by looking it up in the symbol table.

If you can absoluteley exclude this possibility, you could in theory create separate symbol tables for each type. But keep in mind that would obviously make it harder to find name conflicts if you need to detect them and may mean that your programming language is harder to extend later. I wouldn't recommend this solution.

Personally I would just add methods like `to_class()`, `to_var()`, `is_class()`, `is_var()` etc. to your `NodeAST` class, so that the dynamic cast is encapsulated and not spread around the whole codebase. You could also create a class for your symbol table, so that you can access elements with `get_class()`, `get_var()` etc.

If you are concerned about runtime costs of RTTI in C++, you could look at solutions other compilers are using. For LLVM it is described here: http://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Visitor Pattern very successfully in the past to access containers of pointers with a common base. In one implementation I experienced a ~40% speedup over the dynamic_cast<> implementation, which was important in the database abstraction layer I was writing.

There is a little more explanation in one of the answers here ....[Right design pattern to deal with polymorphic collections of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773359/right-design-pattern-to-deal-with-polymorphic-collections-of-objects)

The Wikipedia page on [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Sources) also gives a nice short C++ example of a collection of base pointers being visited by a Dispatcher class.

You have shown the source code for a "visitable" class in your question. We need to see the implementation of your "visitor" to see why you would need a dynamic_cast<>. It shouldn't be necessary. The correct visit() function to use should be chosen through function parameter overloading.

Cheers

Comment: There is no need to downcast in a non-templated implementation of a visitor pattern (search for the Loki library if you want to investigate a generic visitor implementation using templates). Not sure the accepted answer is correct, but dont have the reputation to comment on it!

Comment: For inserting into the symbol table, I traverse the AST using the visitor pattern and insert the named values. That works great. The problem is in my TypeCheckVisitor class. Again, I traverse using the visitor pattern and perform the analysis for each AST node. During the analysis, I need to query the symbol table. For example, I need to get the types of LHS and RHS in a BinaryOperator node. I need those types within the typeCheckBinaryOperator function that I'm currently in (as a result of the Visitor pattern). I don't see how to do that without downcasting LHS and RHS to variables first.