# Struggling with design decision regarding polymorphic member

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am trying to design something that doesn't rely on casting. I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566771/calling-a-non-virtual-function-in-derived-class-using-a-base-class-pointer) and I believe ultimately there is a better way, so I'm asking for advice.

I have a generic `Object` of which there will be subclasses.

I have generic `Node` objects which contain as a member a pointer to an `Object`. `Node`s can be subclassed to offer more specific behaviour about how to handle their `Object` as well as to set what type of subclassed `Object` that particular node is using.

The problem is that my base class requires as a member `Object * myObject` so that my app can traverse all the `Node`s and call a `draw` function on all the `myObject`s.

But how to handle the situation of a subclassed Node calling custom functions on a subclassed Object? These functions could be truly unique and have no place in a base class.

One option I considered is for the subclass to store its pointer member as `MyObjectSubclass * myObject` but a subclass cannot override a base class member, right? So that doesn't really work.

I'd appreciate a more experienced advice for this type of design.

Comment: I have found a 5 year old question with a rather confident answer suggesting that downcasting is perfectly acceptable in this case. The question is quite similar to mine above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/298590/768472

Answer (score 0):

Work with interfaces. Have each Object child inherit from interfaces appropriate for that class, and give the base Object class a method that can retrieve the interfaces.

This is the way Microsoft's COM works.

Comment: @Fellowshee, dual or even more. As many interfaces as are required.

Comment: @Fellowshee, in fact your base class could be an interface too, IDrawable for example.

Comment: Why is it considered better then using `dynamic_cast`? By making Object provide those interfaces you violate `classes should be opened to extensions but closed to modifications` because in case you add more subclasses you'll have to alter base class. At the same time quering subclass interface from base class also may return you `nullptr` - the same way as `dynamic_cast`, though `dynamic_cast` does not violate `extension/modification` principle

Comment: @Andrew I agree that this is a confusing proposition and without a concrete example I am unable to fully understand its relevance or power in this case. I suspect there are better solutions for my use case.